# Calculating density of states from lists of momentum/energy data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, physics

I am trying to calculate the density of states for a 2D system given certain band structure data organized in a specific format. Below is an example of my procedure:

Beginning with a simple 2 x 2 Hamiltonian in which `kx`, `ky` represent the momenta in the x and y directions, respectively:

```
ClearAll
ε1 = -2*t*Cos[kx]; 
ε2 = -2*t*Cos[ky]; 
ε12 = 0.3*t*Sin[kx]*Sin[ky]; 
t = 1; 
λ = 2.5;   
h = {{ε1, ε12 + I*λ}, {ε12 - I*λ, ε2}};
```

I wrote a loop which diagonalizes the above Hamiltonian at different momenta and calculates the energy (eigenvalues) at each `kx/ky` pair, appending a 3-vector consisting of a particular pair of momenta and a corresponding energy (i.e `{px, py, Max[e1, e1]}`) to a list (`dos1` or `dos2`) at each iteration:

```
n = 100; 
dos1 = {}; 
dos2 = {}; 
For[i = 0, i < n, i++,
  For[j = 0, j < n, j++, 
    px = -Pi + 2*Pi*(i/n) + 2*(Pi/(2*n)); 
    py = -Pi + 2*Pi*(j/n) + 2*(Pi/(2*n)); 
    e1 = Eigenvalues[h /. {kx -> px, ky -> py}][[1]]; 
    e2 = Eigenvalues[h /. {kx -> px, ky -> py}][[2]]; 
    dos1 = Append[dos1, {px, py, Max[e1, e2]}];
    dos2 = Append[dos2, {px, py, Min[e1, e2]}];];];
```

Everything works fine up to here. I can plot the band structure (a `ListPlot3D` plot of `dos1` and `dos2` resulting from the previous loop),

I want to calculate and plot the density of states in the following way:

I wish to define a small energy increment (i.e., an interval within `dostot[[m, 3]]` where `dostot = Union[dos1, dos2]` and `m` is just a counter) and for each energy increment over the whole spectrum, count the number of momenta corresponding to the energies in that interval. I'm thinking something like this (counting only x-direction momenta).

```
dostot = Union[dos1, dos2];     
dosx = {}; 
For[m = 1, m <= 20000, m++,
  de = Interval[dostot[[m,3]] - 0.2, dostot[[m,3]] + 0.2]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= 20000, i++, 
    dosx = Append[dosx, Count[de, dostot[[i,1]]]];];]; 
ListPlot[dosx]
```

Obviously this can't work because `dostot[[i, 1]]` is a `kx` momentum which is not an energy like `dostot[[m, 3]]`, so how can I count the momentum corresponding to each energy increment `de`, and how can I avoid appending all the zeroes which result when a momentum is not inside an energy interval associated with a particular `m`?

The final plot would have energy (in the specified increments) along the horizontal axis and the density of states (number of momenta in each energy range) on the vertical axis.

Comment: `ClearAll` is not a command that clears anything. Standing alone as you used it, It is just a symbol without any value. Perhaps you want ``Clear["Global`*"] ``

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
dostot = Union[dos1, dos2][[All, 3]];

{emin, emax} = MinMax[dostot];

de = .25;

Histogram[dostot, {emin, emax, de}, "ProbabilityDensity"]
```

[image: dos]

The definition of `dostot` differs from yours in that I discard all the coordinate values that would only be needed to make 3D plots. The relevant energy is stored as the third component of each entry, so I only keep that part by doing `Union[dos1, dos2][[All, 3]]`. The rest is the implementation of your counting idea by using [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) with a manual specification of the bin width `de` corresponding to the energy increment.

Here is what the plot looks like when the bin width is made smaller:

```
de = .05;

Histogram[dostot, {emin, emax, de}, "ProbabilityDensity"]
```

[image: dos2]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much for your excellent answer!

Comment: And how about unidimensional DOS?